# Passing a variable through url in laravel

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

I'm fairly new to laravel and I'm struggling to get the format of my url correct.

It formats as `http://mysite/blog?category1` instead of `http://mysite/blog/category1`

These are the files I am using. Is there a way to put the route into the `BlogController`?

Route.php

```
Route::get('blog/{category}', function($category = null)
{
    // get all the blog stuff from database
    // if a category was passed, use that
    // if no category, get all posts
    if ($category)
        $posts = Post::where('category', '=', $category)->get();
    else
        $posts = Post::all();

    // show the view with blog posts (app/views/blog.blade.php)
    return View::make('blog.index')
        ->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

Blogcontroller

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        // get the posts from the database by asking the Active Record for "all"
        $posts = Post::all();

        // and create a view which we return - note dot syntax to go into folder
        return View::make('blog.index', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
}
```

blog.index blade

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    <h2>{{ $post->id }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $post->category }}</p>
     <h2>{{ HTML::link(
    action('BlogController@index',array($post->category)),
    $post->category)}}


@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you on apache or nginx, I think this is a rewrite problem of the url.

Comment: What do you mean by "It formats as" ? When you type into the browser? Or the links generated by Laravel?

Comment: The link generated by laravel from the db. it now display as http://localhost/blog?category=category1 and it also doesn't filter the db results so something is wrong somewhere

Answer (score 6):

routes.php

```
Route::get('category', 'CategoryController@indexExternal');
```

*.blade.php print the completed url

```
<a href="{{url('category/'.$category->id.'/subcategory')}}" class="btn btn-primary" >Ver más</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new route in:

```
Route::get('blog/{category}', ['as' => 'post.path', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getCategory']);
```

and added a new link into **index.blade:**

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('post.path', [$post->category]) }}">{{ $post->category }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function as callback for your `Route::get` use a controller and an action:

```
Route::get('blog/{category}', 'BlogController@getCategory');
```

Now in your `BlogController` you can create your function.

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        // get the posts from the database by asking the Active Record for "all"
        $posts = Post::all();

        // and create a view which we return - note dot syntax to go into folder
        return View::make('blog.index', array('posts' => $posts));
    }

    /**
     *  Your new function.
     */
    public function getCategory($category = null)
    {
        // get all the blog stuff from database
        // if a category was passed, use that
        // if no category, get all posts
        if ($category)
            $posts = Post::where('category', '=', $category)->get();
        else
            $posts = Post::all();

        // show the view with blog posts (app/views/blog.blade.php)
        return View::make('blog.index')
            ->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To display your links in your view, you should use `HTML::linkAction` instead of `HTML::link`:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    <h2>{{ $post->id }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $post->category }}</p>
    {{ HTML::linkAction('BlogController@index', "Linkname", array('category' => $post->category)) }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code but it still displays the link with the ? instead of the /.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code with the above and it still displays the link as http://mysite/blog?category1 instead of http://mysite/blog/category1

Comment: in my app in my url i place ?category=1 and then in my controller i extract the variable with category = Input::get('category');

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the alternative .htaccess as shown in the documentation?
Here you go:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You need to place it in the `public` folder of your application.

Here is the original .htaccess in case you don't have it for whatever reason

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have just tried this and no luck it still displays in the same way

Comment: Can you try to enter some junk value into your `.htaccess` to verify if it works? If it works you should get a `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Well at least the .htaccess is working. We need more information such as whether you are on apache or nginx and what server environment you are working on (LAMP, WAMP,...) - also: is mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and i am running on xampp. Just to be clear if i got to mysite/blog/category1 manually, it displays the correct result. However it still outputs the url as mysite/blog?category1 using the laravel HTML:Link